# java bufferreader read elements equal to another array elements

Tags: java, arrays, compare, filestream, readline

I read a file by using bufferreader and also have another array(array_to_compare_with). So, I want to compare these two data.
How can I get over this ? Anybody has a clue ?

```
String[] array_to_compare_with = { "str1","str2","str3","str4" }

FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("filename");

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
// strLine and array_to_compare_with comparison needed to be done
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by compare? do you want to check if its in the array?

Comment: i mean that if strLine has "str1" element or not. If it has than str1 element is found will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
    String[] array_to_compare_with = { "str1","str2","str3","str4" };

    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("filename");

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        boolean found = false;
        for(String str : array_to_compare_with){
            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(strLine.trim())){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found){
            //DO WHAT YOU WHANT
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array_to_compare_with = { "str1","str2","str3","str4" }

FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("filename");

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String strLine;

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    for(String s: array_to_compare_with){
        if(strLine.contains(s)){
            System.out.println(strLine);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```